# NSTextView paste: how to paste "bar" instead when "foo" is pasted?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

I have a NSTextView, where the user can paste plain text into.

When the users has "foo" in the pasteboard I would like "bar" to be pasted. In other words, a user goes to, say, a web browser, selects "foo", cmd+c, switches to my NSTextView, cmd+v and "bar" appears at insertion point.

Please, does anyone know how to approach this?

Edit: is it possible to somehow use `readSelectionFromPasteboard:type:` for this? I just don't know what to put in the method body of my overridden textview..?

Comment: Is it a very specific text replacement function?

Comment: That determines the complexity of the answer

Comment: @DanF: it just replaces string "foo" with string "bar". Plain text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this. Subclass your text view, and override paste: this way:

```
@implementation RDTextView

-(void)paste:(id)sender {
    NSPasteboard *pb = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    NSString *pbItem = [pb readObjectsForClasses: @[[NSString class],[NSAttributedString class]] options:nil].lastObject;
    if ([pbItem isKindOfClass:[NSAttributedString class]]) 
        pbItem = [(NSAttributedString *)pbItem string];

    if ([pbItem isEqualToString:@"foo"]) {
        [self insertText:@"bar"];
    }else{
        [super paste:sender];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks! Please, I have one more question: this "destroys" "foo" in pasteboard, so if I paste in this textview and then paste again in another application it will paste "bar", right? - is it possible to keep this foo/bar "adjustment" "local" to my textview? I mean, not to use `writeObjects`?

Comment: @EcirHana Yes, it's possible. See my edited answer. This version also does the substitution if the "foo" that's picked up is an attributed string (rich text) rather than just a pain string.